# Splash Screens in Android

Tags: android, splash-screen

Everyone who roams the great sea of data referred to as the internet says in response to the question "How do you make a splash screen in android?" "Don't". Ok ... so ... what should you do if you have an app whose whole purpose is to run a linear plus time algorithm on a data set that takes a couple of seconds to load (aka visiting the elements in order).

Answer (score 3):

Despite everyone saying that, most apps still use them for exactly this reason.

Some will try to load stuff on the spot for faster load times but as long as you don't show it for an excessively long time it's not a big deal.

My preferred method for doing this is to trigger an `AsyncTask` to initialise everything on a background thread, then in the `OnPostExecute` callback swap to the main UI for the app.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement an `AsyncTask` and use a `ProgressBar` with it. You can start and stop the `ProgressBar` in `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods respectively. And you can do tha database job in `doInBackground` method.

Answer (score 1):

In general it depends on particular app. But it's always better to decline using `splash screen` because nobody like to see any progress. So just ask your self:

1. If your app can't work without some preparation on start then use splash screen.
2. If just only a part of your app can't work with preparation then do it in background and show some progress to your user.

More over `cold start` of an app is very important user experience thing, so you should decrease  start up time as much as possible.